# PyQt5 - How to display image in QMainWindow class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qmainwindow

I'm trying to display a picture in a QMainWindow class:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import sys


class Menu(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Title")
        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('capture.png')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Menu()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But it doesn't show the image, just opens the window. I'm insisting on a `QMainWindow` class because I'm trying to write something like a paint app, so I'll be able to write a menu, and I'll be able to write on the picture.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Not related to your question but what version of python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.6.5 Anaconda

Comment: have you tried with a jpg image?

Comment: You're misusing `QMainWindow`.  Look at [`QMainWindow::setCentralWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget).

Comment: @TheCrystalShip Ah I see, so are you working from Unix system or DOS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> QMainWindow.setCentralWidget(widget)
>
> Sets the given widget to be the main window’s central widget.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import sys


class Menu(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Title")
        
        self.central_widget = QWidget()               
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)    
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        
        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('logo.png')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
        
        lay.addWidget(label)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Menu()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. It will help a lot if you check this question as well - https://stackoverflow.com/q/51635438/8563092

Comment: @TheCrystalShip try it